# Windows asks me to activate my product key – what do I have to do?

Tags: windows, windows-activation

I downloaded a copy of Windows 7 Home Premium to my computer. Now there are messages popping up saying "activate your product key".

What should I do now? All my Microsoft programs title bars has turned into red, showing the above message.

Do I have to get a genuine product key for this? and what should I do with this?

Comment: Where did you get your product key from?

Comment: You mean installed on your computer, not "downloaded" to it, right? You had to enter the product key when you installed it. Did you activate Windows when it prompted you?

Comment: You activate your product by entering a valid Windows 7 Home Premium license.

Comment: sounds like OFFICE needs to be activated

Answer (score 3):

> All my Microsoft programs title bars has turned into red

Sounds like OFFICE needs to be activated, not windows

assuming the key you used was legit, you can activate Office from the comand line.

From the command prompt:

```
cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ospp.vbs" /act
```

If you don't have a key, you'll need to get a legit one.

You could even use the ospp.vbs script to add one once you get one.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've bought a genuine copy, you should have a key and need to [activate within 30 days per the instructions here.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows#1TC=windows-7)